# Run PowerShell script with Service Start

Tags: powershell, windows-service, start, affinity, process-priority

I'd like to set the `Affinity` and `Priority` of a service process when it is started (***without*** modifying the service/process code, I **don't** own the code, it's a 3rd party service).

I know I can do:

`$Process = Get-Process MyService
$Process.ProcessorAffinity = 4`

in **PowerShell** to change the `Affinity` of the process or prefix the command path with:

`cmd.exe /c start "Some Process Name" /affinity 4`

However, ***neither*** of these are applicable to changing the `Affinity` and `Priority` of the service's process automatically **everytime** the service is started)  How can I do this ***without*** using some 3rd-party app that 'maintains' process affinity across restart (I'd ***really*** like to write/create a solution myself and not rely yet another app to 'configure' windows).

Comment: Couldn't you set a scheduled task in Windows to run a Powershell script $Process = Get-Process MyService
$Process.ProcessorAffinity = 4 
everytime the service is restarted?  Just thinking out loud.  That may not work though.

Comment: Art.Vandelay05's idea should work.  Create a script to change process affinity and  create an event trigger in Task Scheduler which runs the script after the service is restarted.

Comment: Yeah, bentek, that's what I was thinking of: event trigger.  That should do what you want XyberICE. I just wasn't sure if your 3rd party service would generate an event ID when it restarts.

Comment: @Art.Vandelay05 Thanks!  I think this will be the easiest solution for me to implement 'cause I've aleady done each of these steps (separately for other purposes).  I'll give it a try on Mon and let you know how it works.

Comment: Sweet!  I can't wait to hear back.  In task scheduler I have setup AD scripts to run when specific Security Event IDs are generated, e.g., when a new user is created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I built on @Art.Vandelay05's comment and here's the (IMHO most ***intuitive***) solution.

1. Create the `Script.ps1` PowerShell script with the following lines:
   `$Process = Get-Process`  *< service_process_exe_name_WITHOUT_the_exe >*
   `$Process.ProcessorAffinity =` *< hex version of bit-code for processor affinity >*
2. Go to `Administrative Tools/Task Scheduler` and `Create Task...` (NOT `Create Basic Task`)
3. **General Tab**

   - *Check Run whether user is logged on or not*
   - *Change User or Group* to a local user on your machine
4. **Triggers**

   - *New...*
   - *Enabled*
   - Begin the task *On an event*
   - *Edit Event Filter*
   - Use a little `XSLT` to find the message for your service starting.  I used:

`<QueryList>
  <Query Id="0" Path="System">
    <Select Path="System"> 
        *[EventData[Data[@Name="param1"] and (Data="`*< your_service_name >* `")]]
        and
        *[EventData[Data[@Name="param2"] and (Data="running")]]
    </Select>
  </Query>
</QueryList>`

5. **Actions**

   - Action *Start a program*
   - Program/script: *PowerShell.exe*
   - Add arguments (optional): *-File "path_to_script\Script.ps1"*

That's it!  Now every time your service runs, the affinity will be set according to the PowerShell script you wrote.

**Edit:**
Make ***sure*** your local user has the `Debug Programs` right (*Administrative Tools/Local Security Policy/User Rights Assignment/Debug programs/*  add your local user to this right) or your user ***won't*** be able to change a process's affinity.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this post :
http://waynes-world-it.blogspot.ca/2009/06/processor-affinity-on-windows-server.html

> If you’re trying to control a service, you could use instsrv/srvany to
>   create a service that wraps the start or psexec command around the
>   real service binary. For example, the commands below create another
>   version of the spooler service that will only run on the first
>   processor.
>
> ```
> instsrv Test c:\util\srvany.exe 
> reg add hklm\system\currentcontrolset\services\test\Parameters
> reg add hklm\system\currentcontrolset\services\test\Parameters /v Application /t reg_sz /d cmd.exe 
> reg add hklm\system\currentcontrolset\services\test\Parameters /v AppParameters /t reg_sz /d "/c start /affinity 1 C:\WINDOWS\system32\spoolsv.exe"
> ```